# Commas do not echo with line

Tags: arrays, shell, csv

I have a file that contains multiple lines, kind of like a log.  Each column in the file is separated by a comma.  I am using an array to echo the lines to the output but when I run the script against the file, it does not seem to include the commas.  They are in the file, why do they not print?  Here is my code;  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
while IFS=, read -ra line;
do
    if [ "${line[1]}" != "" ]
    then
        echo -n "${line[@]}, Hash Value: " && echo "${line[1]}" | openssl dgst -sha1 | sed 's/^.* //'
    else
        break
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (though it would help if you can provide sample input):

```
while IFS=, read -ra line;
do
    if [ "${line[1]}" != "" ]
    then
        (IFS=, ; line="${line[*]}"; echo -n "$line, Hash Value: ") && echo "${line[1]}" | openssl dgst -sha1 | sed 's/^.* //'
    else
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: @JS, thanks for the reply!  I actually figured it out not too long ago.  I just took the IFS=, out of the while loop and placed it above.  This would do the same thing though.  Thanks a bunch!! (I'd give you a 1 up but don't have enough reputation points).  Thanks again